# How do I load a collada file in Away3d broomstick

Tags: away3d

Do you have an example of loading a 3d object and displaying it from a collada file?  I've browsed around and haven't found a good example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that in Broomstick version is Collada file loading not yet implemented. Available parsers are AC3D, AWD, MD2, MD5, 3DS and OBJ (see [git hub parses source folder](https://github.com/away3d/away3d-core-fp11/tree/master/src/away3d/loaders/parsers))..